# Round 916.984800 to 916.99

Tags: sql-server, decimal, rounding

Is it possible to round 916.984800 to 916.99 in SQL Server?

I've tried as below but I don't want '+ 0.1' as my solution.

```
Round((((424.53 - 0) * 36) * (6 / 100)),2) + .01 as [Amount]
```

or

```
Round((((424.53 - 0) * 36) * (0.06)),2) + .01 as [Amount]
```

Thanks

Comment: There's no obvious rounding algorithm that will round ".9848" to ".99", because that's clearly closer to ".98" than to ".99". What are your desired rules? What should ".9847" round to? How about ".984"? How about ".980000001"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This produces expected output:

```
SELECT CEILING((424.53 - 0) * 36 * 0.06 * 100) / 100  AS [Amount]

Amount
----------
916.990000
```

What happens?

```
SELECT (424.53 - 0) * 36 * 0.06 * 100
```

This returns `91698.4800`, [CEILING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189818.aspx) returns the smallest integer greater than, or equal to, the specified numeric expression, in your case `91699`, and later I just divide it by 100, which brings expected result.